# Why does my application stop running, while it has a while(true) loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that is meant to "run forever". To achieve that, my code is under a while(true) loop.

```
while(true){

   //My code is here 
   //What it does is that it calls some Url, 
   //gets xml, parses it and stores the values to a db.

}
```

This application runs as a java application and runs on jdk 5 on Redhat Linux. After a day or two, I realize that the log has activities of even 5 days ago, meaning that it stopped working 5 days ago. But when I check the java processes in the machine, this application shows that it is running.

Question: Why is this so??

Comment: How are we supposed to know without some actual code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A probable cause is that an exception is being thrown while processing those urls which is cought and consumed by your code, so the processing is failing but the application continues running. Unfortunately you have shown only comments, not any real code, so this is only a hypothesis.

Comment: This was actually the main reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities, but without more code I can't precisely narrow it down to which one specifically it is.  Here are some thoughts:

1. There could be a `break` statement somewhere in the loop that explicitly leaves the loop.
2. If your loop is in a function and something in the loop `return`s from the function, you would leave the loop.
3. If something in the loop throws an uncaught exception, the loop would terminate.  This also includes things like `OutOfMemoryError`s or `StackOverflowError`s.
4. The JVM might have crashed overnight due to an unusual bug.
5. An external process killed the JVM.
6. The system rebooted to install an update or because someone logged in and ran `sudo reboot now`.
7. The laws of boolean arithmetic changed, and now `true == false`. :-)

Comment: I think 4, 5 and 6 are not the cause in this situation since he says the application is still running, only the Thread is stopped. So I go with 7 ;)

Comment: 7. Could mean a simple bug in the == operator. ;)

Comment: This seems like an "obvious" question from the manner I framed it, but it is not that obvious. I have "caught" every trhowable in my appliction. Here is another observation; This application runs on over 10 servers distributed across different countries. In some servers, the application will run say, 10days longer before it fails, in some servers it will run for only a week, in some, over a month...They are using different JRE versions and I am thinking that this could be a factor... I am still observing these applications closely, maybe later I can re-phrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

Log the exception:

```
try{
    while(true){
       // ......
    }
}catch(Throwable t){
  //log the Throwable object
}
```